# The DOM tree is showing the title tag inside the BODY section and not in the HEAD section in the LIVE DOM viewer? Why is this happening?

Tags: html, dom

In order to check the working of the DOM tree (actually to check how it works if I don't put the tags orderly or write random text without using any tag) I touched upon the LIVE DOM viewer.

As I write a title before a text, DOM tree shows it in the HEAD section just the right way:

input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>XYZ</title>
random text
```

Output(what the DOM viewer shows):

```
DOCTYPE: html
 HTML
   HEAD
     TITLE
       #text: XYZ
         #text:
   BODY
       #text: random text
```

but when I write a text before the title tag, it shows the title in the BODY section and not in HEAD. Why is that happening? :

input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
random text
<title>XYZ</title>
```

output:

```
DOCTYPE: html
  HTML
    HEAD
    BODY
        #text: random text
        TITLE
        #text: XYZ
        #text:
```

Comment: Don't use StackSnippets if there is no code to run.

Comment: *"Why is that happening?"* Most likely because both HTML snippets are invalid and the browser does its best to fix them. Since there cannot be any (non-empty) text *before* the `<body>` tag, it seems to move everything inside the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when the parser sees some text directly inside the head, the [insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insertion-mode) is switched to "[in body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody)", so the text appears inside the `body` elements. Following `title` elements won't be moved to the `head`, because it has already been completely parsed.

Specifically, this code ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>XYZ</title>
random text
```

... is parsed as follows:

1. The insertion mode is initially set to "[initial](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-initial-insertion-mode)"
2. The parser sees a DOCTYPE token. The insertion mode is switched to "[before html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode)".
3. The parser sees a line break, which is ignored.
4. The parser a `<title>` start tag. An `html` element is created. The insertion mode is switched to "[before head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode)", and the token is reprocessed.
5. The parser a `<title>` start tag. A `head` start tag is inserted. The insertion mode is switched to "[in head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead)", and the token is reprocessed.
6. The parser a `<title>` start tag. The [generic RCDATA element parsing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#generic-rcdata-element-parsing-algorithm) is followed.
7. A `title` element is [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-an-html-element). The insertion mode is switched to "[text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-incdata)".
8. The parser sees some text. The characters are [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-a-character).
9. The parser sees a `</title>` end tag. The `title` element is popped off the stack of open elements. The insertion mode is switched to the original one.
10. The parser sees some text. The `head` element is popped off the [stack of open elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#stack-of-open-elements). The insertion mode is switched to "[after head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode)", and the token is reprocessed.
11. The parser sees some text. A `body` start tag is inserted. The insertion mode is switched to "[in body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody)", and the token is reprocessed.
12. The parser sees some text. The characters are [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-a-character).
13. The parser sees an end-of-file token. [The end](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-end)

And this code ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
random text
<title>XYZ</title>
```

... is parsed as follows:

1. The insertion mode is initially set to "[initial](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-initial-insertion-mode)"
2. The parser sees a DOCTYPE token. The insertion mode is switched to "[before html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode)".
3. The parser sees a line break, which is ignored.
4. The parser sees some text. An `html` element is created. The insertion mode is switched to "[before head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode)", and the token is reprocessed.
5. The parser sees some text. A `head` start tag is inserted. The insertion mode is switched to "[in head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead)", and the token is reprocessed.
6. The parser sees some text. The `head` element is popped off the [stack of open elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#stack-of-open-elements). The insertion mode is switched to "[after head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode)", and the token is reprocessed.
7. The parser sees some text. A `body` start tag is inserted. The insertion mode is switched to "[in body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody)", and the token is reprocessed.
8. The parser sees some text. The characters are [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-a-character).
9. The parser sees a `<title>` start tag. The token is processed using "[in head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead)" insertion mode.
10. The parser sees a `<title>` start tag. The [generic RCDATA element parsing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#generic-rcdata-element-parsing-algorithm) is followed.
11. A `title` element is [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-an-html-element). The insertion mode is switched to "[text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-incdata)".
12. The parser sees some text. The characters are [inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-a-character).
13. The parser sees a `</title>` end tag. The `title` element is popped off the stack of open elements. The insertion mode is switched to the original one.
14. The parser sees an end-of-file token. [The end](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-end)

Comment: Nice! Learned something new again :)

Comment: @Oriol Thanks. One more thing, by `text` you mean the texts written without any tags or in tags like `<p>`, `<h1>`.. and NOT the ones written in metadata tags like `<title>` or `<noscript>`, right? Because as you said as the parser sees the `text`, insertion mode is switched to `in body` which is what's happening in pt. 7 in the second case where it sees the text and completes the `HEAD` without inserting anything. But in first case when `HEAD` was getting parsed, it saw the `text` in the title tag BUT didn't switch to `in body` and rather inserted the text in the tree, which is contradictory?

Comment: When I said "text" I meant `random text` or `XYZ` (well, I think the parser parses the text character by character instead of as a whole, but doesn't matter much). But yes you are right, if the text is inside a `title` element in the head the insertion mode isn't switched to "in body", I have clarified the summary.

Comment: ok, thanks a tonne Oriol! That was a great help :). But one more thing, what if i write :  !DOCTYPE <head> some text </head> ? In this case also, as you said, as soon as the parser sees the text, the head tag will be popped off the stack of open elements and insertion mode will be changed to original. So now what if it sees a closed </head> tag next? where will this closed tag be inserted then?

Comment: @YoshitaArora When the parser sees that text, the `head` element is closed and the insertion mode is switched to "in body". Then the `</head>` end tag is a parse error and is ignored.